# Are you able to move divs up and down when their CSS positioning is "initial"?

Tags: html, css, positioning

My div class's css:

```
.post {
position:initial;
}
```

Are you able to move this div up by using something like top:-10px; etc?

Comment: maybe `margin-top: -10px;`

Answer (score 2):

The initial value for the [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) poperty is `static` and with static positioning, you cannot adjust the physical position of an element on-screen using `bottom`, `left`, `right` or `top`.

Your three options are to either:

1. Use a `margin`. In the example provided in your question, you would use `margin-top:-10px` or `margin:-10px 0 0`
2. Use the CSS `transform` property with a `translateX()` or `translateY()` value. Again, from your exmaple, that would be `transform:translatey(-10px)`. (Don't forget to prefix this one as applicable)
3. Change the value of your `position` attribute to `relative`, which would allow you to use `bottom`, `left`, `right` and/or `top` to move the element around, relative to its original position, without removing it from the document flow, as would happen with `absolute` positioning.

Comment: Updated to include an option using `transform`; don't know why I omitted that originally.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to use the default top/bottom/left/right, you would utilize margin then apply negative or positive values depending were you would need it positioned.

```
div { 
    position: initial;
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: -10px;
    /* You can use margin of course as well: margin: -10px 0px 0px 0px; */
}
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eacv95jg/1/)